# Is there a way this below line of code would work? Am trying to have the WhatsApp open on a different page

Tags: php, html, api, whatsapp

Why is the below line of code not working?
I am trying to have the WhatsApp open on a different page, on my installed WhatsApp on my PC

```
<i>
<li><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=whatsAppNumber&text=Your_Message" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>
</i>
```

Comment: Are you trying to Open Whatsapp ?

Comment: `<li>` doesn't have a `target` attribute. You are most likely missing an `<a href...>` element

Comment: _"Why is the below line of code not working?"_ - Because it doesn't do anything other than outputting "whatsappNumber" in a list. Why would you expect it to do anything else?

Comment: can't understand what you are trying to do. Are u trying to open web.whatsapp.com in another tab?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You have to use an `a` tag. This will open Whatsapp if installed in your device or will open whatsapp web, and will send the `Your_Message` to `your_whatsapp_number`.

```html
<a href="https://wa.me/your_whatsapp_number?text=Your_Message" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>

<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=your_whatsapp_number&text=Your_Message" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked.

Am sorry for those who didn't understand my question. It was my first question but I am now wiser.

Comment: Glad to Hear...

Comment: after using 
<a href="https://wa.me/whats app number?text=Your_Message" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a>

We couldn't find the page you were looking for
Looks like you're looking for a page that doesn't exist. Or a page we might have just deleted. Either way, go back or be sure to check the url, your spelling and try again.

...this is the error am getting instead of being taken directly to my texts in whats app despite having https://web.whatsapp.com/ opened on the same browser.

Comment: @WilsonNjure I have updated the answer with alternate solution. Please try that.

Comment: and the entire community,

<li><a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=whatsAppNUmber&text=Your_Message" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-whatsapp"></i></a></li>

this line of code has worked on android phone with WhatsApp Business only(thanks you very much)....

Could we get one that works across platforms, eg all major browsers and the ones installed WhatsApp on computers?

Comment: This should work on Major Browsers. Atleast it will fallback to Whatsapp Web.